# $_POST not working PHP (no errors)

Tags: php, mysql

I need some help with PHP.
$_POST is not working in PHP.
I'm using MAMP on Mac.

I have no errors returned, no data stored in my DB.

My DB username and password are not switched because I set
the password as 'root'.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'juicysoft', 'root', 'PublicFiles');
$uname = $_POST['uname'];
$pword = $_POST['pword'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (uname, pword, email) VALUES ($uname, $pword, 
$email)';
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
echo "Success!";
}
```

?>

```html
<!-- The form that I need to post -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>PublicFiles - Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="uname" placeholder="Screen Name..."><br>
 <input type="password" name="pword" placeholder="Password..."><br>
 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..."><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Echo `$sql` and you'll see why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$sql` is written incorrect,

Change

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (uname, pword, email) VALUES ($uname, $pword, 
$email)';
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (uname, pword, email) VALUES ('".$uname."','".$pword."','".$email."')";
```

---

NOTE: Set parameter directly into sql may cause **SQL Injection**,you had better use prepared statement to do it

Comment: Except... this doesn't fix the SQL injection problem.

Comment: @Mike,yes,my answer is just focused on his current design

Comment: it shows http error 500.

Comment: @IanPark just update my answer

Comment: That's not a very useful answer if it enables OP to ignore parameter binding. The unhandy concatenation syntax (instead of iinterpolation) makes it even worse.

Comment: @mario Looks like OP doesn't care...